# How to execute and manage ruby script from ruby?

Tags: ruby, execute, health-monitoring

I have a script named program.rb and would like to write a script named main.rb that would do the following:

```
system("ruby", "program.rb")

constantly check if program.rb is running until it is done
if program.rb has reached completion
    exit main.rb
end
otherwise keep doing this until program.rb reaches completion{
if program.rb is not running and stopped before completing
    restart program.rb from where it left off
end}
```

I've looked into Pidify but could not find a way to apply it to fit this exactly the right way...
Any help in how to approach this script would be greatly appreciated!

Update:
I could figure out how to resume running the script from where it left off in program.rb if there's no way to do it in main.rb

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to "restart script from where it left off" without full cooperation from the `program.rb`. That is, it should be able to advertise its progress (by writing current state to a file, maybe?) and be able to start correctly from a step specified in ARGV. There's no external ruby magic that can replace this functionality.

Also, if a program terminated abnormally, it means one of two things:

- the error is (semi-)permanent (disk is full, no appropriate access rights to a file, etc). In this case, simply restarting the program would cause it to fail again. And again. Infinite fail loop.
- the error is temporary (shaky internet connection). In this case, program should do better job with exception handling and retry on its own (instead of terminating).

In either case, there's no need for restarting, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you I was just thinking about that! I could output to a progress file from program.rb and manage where it picks up from in program.rb itself but would still appreciate any help on the rest of the main.rb script!

Comment: @Sergio, actually there is a community producing programs that do this. Off the top of my head, monit, god, foreman, passenger, and upstart all do this, and the first three exist for no other reason. It's quite common to monitor web servers and restart them when they grow too big or crash. They are too complex to run forever. It's not ideal but everything important is in the db so they restarting allows the programs to function commercially despite occasional exceptions. There is another community dedicated to pulling these exceptions out and mailing them to development teams.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: yes, but they just restart. They don't restart from a point.

Comment: @Sergio. Aha, yes. But perhaps his script isn't so stateless.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: yes, that's what I was trying to say. It's unlikely (I think) that his script will be touched by OOM-killer. If there's a `LoadError` (or error of similar severity), restarting won't help. Other errors should be remedied with better exception handling. So, I guess, my answer doesn't actually answer the question. :)

Comment: Yes, the reason that program.rb would fail is because it uses Watir to collect data from a web page that may be slow and not produce data in time. It collects multiple values and if it misses one then the program fails.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is one way.

Modify `program.rb` to take an optional flag argument `--restart` or something.

When `program.rb` starts up without this argument it will initialize a file to record its current state. Periodically, it will write whatever it needs into this file to record some kind of checkpoint.

When `program.rb` starts up *with* the *restart* flag, it will read its checkpoint file and start processing at that point. For this to work, it must either checkpoint all state changes or arrange for all processing between checkpoints to be idempotent so it can be repeated without ill effect.

There are lots of ways to monitor the health of `program.rb`. The best way is with some sort of ping, perhaps something like `GET /health_check` or a dummy message via a socket or pipe. You could just have a locked file to detect if the lock is still held, or you could record the PID on startup and check that it still exists.